# Set popup error message duration in Netzke

Tags: extjs4, netzke

Now I'm working on Rails 3.1.3 with Netzke now.

And I want to config duration of the error message. that show when have field validation error in Grid Panel.

Cause it's very fast fade away (around 1 ~ 1.5 second) and I can't read that in one time (if it's have three or more error).

Can I config this one? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not such config option as `feedback` is defined at global level.
See [source](https://github.com/netzke/netzke-core/blob/master/javascripts/ext.js).

You have several solutions for that problem. One of them is to override definition of that JS class to use different constant delay. Otherwise you could refactor this class to use different beahaviur, for example, additional not required parameter.

Comment: Implemented with https://github.com/netzke/netzke-core/commit/ad6b6721e7e726d91c3ce3d37c2715d3d2deaa8f